# deleting an alert in an "if" statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I have an if statement that currently has an alert pop up when the next button on the page is clicked.  Im not sure what i have to remove to just have the alert go away.  I still need the button to take you to the next page.  No matter what I adjust, the end result is the button no longer works.  Here is the code:

```
$('.dab_button').click(function(){
if($('[name=select_value1]').val()=='' ||
    $('[name=select_value2]').val()=='' ||
    $('[name=select_value3]').val()==''){
        alert('Please select your gift choices for each or the three levels.');             
    } else{
        <? if($members_info['individual']=='no'):?>
            window.location.href = "/dab/profile";
        <? else:?>
            window.location.href = "/hq/edit_page";
        <? endif;?>         
    }     
});
```

Comment: The alert is appearing because you do not have a selection for one of your `select_value`s. Just select something for them. Or do you want to go to the page even if something is not selected?

Answer (score 2):

Just comment it out?

```
$('.dab_button').click(function(){
    if($('[name=select_value1]').val()==""||$('[name=select_value2]').val()==""||$('[name=select_value3]').val()==""){
        ; // do nothing
        // alert('Please select your gift choices for each or the three levels.');             
    } else{
<? if($members_info['individual']=='no'):?>
        window.location.href = "/dab/profile";
<? else:?>
        window.location.href = "/hq/edit_page";
<? endif;?>         
    }     
});
```

But I stronly recommend to give some feedback to the user when the button does nothing (does not navigate away), because they have not filled out all inputs. If you wanted to navigate in any case, just remove that if-statement (note that you also have serverside processing code, which has nothing to do with the javascript):

```
$('.dab_button').click(function(){
<? if($members_info['individual']=='no'):?>
    window.location.href = "/dab/profile";
<? else:?>
    window.location.href = "/hq/edit_page";
<? endif;?>
});
```

Comment: That can be improved by negating the if condition and getting rid of the `else` block. Right now you just have an empty "if true" block

Comment: Yes, of course. That's just because I suggested the OP to fill the gap with some different notification.

Comment: @sachleen, you don't suppose they have unit tests for refactoring of *such* complexity, do you?